# Where to start in Marvel Unlimited

Tags: suggested-order, marvel, marvel-unlimited

I recently purchased an annual membership to Marvel Unlimited which give you access to a ton of different comics in the Marvel Universe, so many I'm having a hard time deciding where to start. I don't have any particular interests although I feel compelled towards the following:

- X-Men
- Avengers
- Spiderman

However there seem to be a lot of comics from different issues and different times and I don't even know where to start reading. Can you make a suggestion for where to start (I'm open to suggestions to any other comics that you think are worth reading regarding other series).

Just for clarification I've already read some stuff about the X-Men (I think from the new series up to the point where Dark Phoenix appear) and some isolated Spiderman comics.

I'm mostly interested in a suggested reading order for those series or, if Marvel Unlimited is releasing some new series that I should read instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using Marvel Unlimited for about three years now and I think you're going to really enjoy the experience.

I put together a detailed list recently of [all the best stuff in the catalog](http://www.comicbookherald.com/best-comics-on-marvel-digital-unlimited/). Check it out if you're so inclined, I'm hoping it's a nice resource for helping new MU subscribers know where to turn.

Otherwise, here's a starting point for each comic:

X-Men: Astonishing X-Men (Issues #1-#24) - Avengers director Joss Whedon writing and John Cassaday on art. Fantastic X-series.

Avengers: New Avengers (starts in 2004 w/ Brian Michael Bendis and carries on through the decade).

Spider-Man: If you haven't before, I'd go back to the original Amazing Spider-Man star with Stan Lee & Steve Ditko. These are still a blast to read. If you're looking to keep it a little more modern, check out Spider-Man: Blue. Good take on the character from the creators of Batman: The Long Halloween.

Hope this all helps, and happy reading!

Answer (score 0):

Marvel is pretty good at recapping information, but it really depends on how far back you want to go.  And there have been some great (and not great) stories all along the way, so no matter where you start you will find books that you didn't read that are worth reading.

I second reading the early spider-man stuff, it is good, and there are some great moments from that comic in the 70s as well.

X-Men you should at least read Days of Future Past story arc, since the new X-Men movie is going to be based off of it.

I and a few other people are trying to read through most of marvels back catalog, and we have marked a bunch of issues as essential to read (meaning it contains information that will be helpful when reading future marvel stuff).  its at http://cmro.travis-starnes.com/